# A ES6 Set unique via inner key value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set, unique

Is it possible to have a unique set based on an inner key with out processing it through a function like [uniquBy](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqBy)?

```
export const state = new Set()

state.add({name: 'dank meme'});
state.add({name: 'dank meme'});

console.log(state.length)
// 2
```

How can I make this Set unique by name value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. Adding equal objects to a `Set` as you do does result in two objects added to the set because they are *distinct* objects (different references), accidentally with the same content.
You should build a new class, perhaps inheriting from `Set`, implementing the behaviour you ask.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll do that.